# php set headers for requested image

Tags: php, android, apache, picasso

Simply,

if the url requested is that of an image, like myserverpath/image.jpg, then how can I set headers for this? Also, I have some custom logic before headers can be set. So, how can this be done?

Specifically:

I'm using picasso library to load images:

```
String url = myserverpath/image.jpg

Picasso.with(context)
                .load(url)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_contact_picture)
                .error(R.drawable.ic_contact_picture)
                .into(imageView);
```

Gradle dependencies:

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.+'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.+'
```

Picasso uses OkHttp (Http client) internally to take correct actions for headers like cache control etc.

Now, I want to set headers using php, like:

```
header('Cache-Control: public');
//check if page has changed. If not, send 304 and exit
if (@strtotime($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE'])==$lastModified || $etagHeader == $etagFile)
{
       header("HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified");
       exit;
}
```

But since the url in picasso is a .jpg file and not .php file (where I can set headers), how can I set the headers?

Comment: You can set the headers in your server configuration. In Apache for example it's in `httpd.conf` or `.htaccess`

Comment: @KenWolf I have some custom logic before setting these headers, like first comparing incoming request header values and then setting respective headers, how can this be done?

Comment: This is all done server-side. Please tag with whatever your server is, you might get more responses.

Comment: Unsure what PHP has to do with any of this since you're apparently using Java and a Java http client.

Comment: @KenWolf added apache server tag

Comment: @Satisfaction I want to set cache control and other headers. This should be done at server side and not client side, isn't it?